# How can I maintain the aspect ratio of my background image when using background-size: cover;?

Tags: html, css, debugging

I'm dealing with a background image.

Is there a way I can maintain the aspect ratio of my image even after using `background-size: cover;`?  My image fits perfectly to screen but at the same time - it's a little smushed.  I've tried `height: auto;` or any other value for `height` but it looks like `background-size: cover;` doesn't allow height to be manipulated.

Is there a way to manipulate height? In other words, stretch the background image vertically without smushing the image?

Comment: It is already maintained when you use cover.

Comment: Can you post the code in addition to the description?

Comment: @WaisKamal ahhh sorry, I meant `background-repeat: round;` :(

Answer (score -1):

As you can see by the snippet, background-size: cover already maintains aspect ratio.

```css
.bg-me{
  background-image: url('https://assets.atlasobscura.com/media/W1siZiIsInVwbG9hZHMvcGxhY2VfaW1hZ2VzLzA0MzRjZGI4MTJlNjdkMzBmNV93aW5kb3dzX3hwX2JsaXNzLXdpZGUuanBnIl0sWyJwIiwidGh1bWIiLCJ4MzkwPiJdLFsicCIsImNvbnZlcnQiLCItcXVhbGl0eSA4MSAtYXV0by1vcmllbnQiXV0/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg-me"> </div>
```